# Compare a javascript function with a php variable

Tags: php, javascript, compare

I have found a javascript function that gets the name of a country when it is clicked on a map and a php snippet which gets the name of a country randomly from a file. What I want to do is to compare the result between these two so that I can tell if the user clcked on the map the right country according to the one appearing above in the question. I am not sure how to do it since they are not exactly simple variables and I tried to assign the php variable to a javascript one with no luck. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
     ....  
        function getCountry(latLng) {
                geocoder.geocode( {'latLng': latLng},
                  function(results, status) {
                    if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                      if(results[0]) {
                        for(var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                          if(results[0].address_components[i].types[0] == "country") {
                            alert(results[0].address_components[i].long_name);
                          }
                        }
                      }
                      else {
                        alert("No results");
                      }
                    }
                    else {
                      alert("Status: " + status);
                    }
                  }
                );
              }


 ....

    Can you locate <?php
        $countries=file("countries.txt");
        $number_countries=count($countries);
        if($number_countries!==0){$number_countries.=-1;};
        $random=rand(0,$number_countries);
        $countryy=$countries[$random];
        echo "$countryy";
        ?>   on the map?
```

Comment: *sigh* so tired of seeing these...PHP is server-side, JavaScript is client-side. They only communicate by you writing your PHP data into the script during render time, or the JavaScript sending an Ajax request. You can't just do `$phpvar === jsVar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bad practice, you should use ajax, but here is what you want.

```
Can you locate <?php
    $countries=file("countries.txt");
    $number_countries=count($countries);
    if($number_countries!==0){$number_countries.=-1;};
    $random=rand(0,$number_countries);
    $countryy=$countries[$random];
    echo "$countryy";
    ?>   on the map?
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var country = <?php echo json_encode($countryy); ?>

      function getCountry(latLng) {
              geocoder.geocode( {'latLng': latLng},
                function(results, status) {
                  if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    if(results[0]) {
                      for(var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
                        if(results[0].address_components[i].types[0] == "country") {
                           if(results[0].address_components[i].long_name == country) {
                              alert("right");
                           } else {
                              alert("wrong");
                           }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                    else {
                      alert("No results");
                    }
                  }
                  else {
                    alert("Status: " + status);
                  }
                }
              );
      }
  </script>
```

Comment: i keep on getting "wrong".. I think that by assigning the php variable to var country I can't get the result of the country inside the function from google maps.

Comment: I replaced the php part with a javascript one and it worked. Either way thank you very much! p.s. I know I'm not using the best way but I'm really new at all this so I'm just trying to find a way to handle it all.